# Cambiar texto de un label con javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos, webforms

Saludos. Tengo un evento Onblur en un `Textbox`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="us" runat="server"  MaxLength="15" onblur="validar(this.id)" Width="232px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Luego un `Label`:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="esto es un texto" ></asp:Label>
```

Y un metodo en javascript:

```
<script> 

    function validar(x){
        //He intentado con: document.all("Label1").innerText = "Esto es otro texto"; Pero nada           
      //Incluso document.getElementById("Label1").innerHTML = "Esto es otro texto"; Y tampoco
    }          

</script>
```

¿Como puedo lograr esto ya sea cambiando el texto directamente o habilitarlo desde CSS cada vez que pierda el foco del `Textbox`?

Answer (score 2):

Con Javascript puedes probar

```
document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML= 'Nuevo valor';
```

Con jquery puedes probar

```
$('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>').html("Nuevo valor");
```

Comment: Nota: Esto sería usando Jquery

Comment: Mil disculpas, era con javascript @Bitito gracias!

Comment: No hay por qué disculparse, quizás le sirva usar jQuery :P

Comment: Probe de la segunda manera y resulta que se reconoce 'Label1'. ¿Esto se debe a que lo estoy haciendo desde la pagina maestra y el Label esta en otra pagina? Y si es asi ¿Como hago el puente en ambas paginas para que la pagina maestra pueda reconocer el Label ubicado en otra?

Comment: Desconozco lo que necesitas, porque quieres desde la pagina maestra obtener un label de una pagina que se compone de? No seria lo mejor obtenerla en la misma view?

Comment: No soy muy bueno usando jquery :/ Pero podria hacer una excepcion en este caso. ¿Como quedaria el codigo usando jquery desde <script> hasta </script>?

Comment: Dejalo con javascript, en mi respuesta el primer ejemplo esta con javascript

Comment: @sioesi, resulta que cuando uso ('#<%=Label1.ClientID%>'), siempre me marca el nombre del Label, o de lo que sea, como un nombre que no se encuentra en el contexto actual, pero cuando uso por ejemplo  document.getElementById("contol") Funciona.

Comment: Cuando hago esto  document.getElementById("el_span").style.display = 'none'; Me va de maravilla. Y el script esta en la pagina maestra y el_span en otra pagina

Comment: puedes cambiar igual el asp indicadole el id que deseas con la propiedad ClientId `<asp:Label ID="Label1" ClientID="___Label1" runat="server" Text="esto es un texto" ></asp:Label>` despues haces tu script document.getElementsById("___Label1"), o jQuery: `$("#___Label1")`

Comment: Nada aun :c Y necesito un label ya que tambien debo modificarlo desde c#, no solo desde javascript. Con un span me funciona lo que pretendo hacer con el label. Pero un span no puedo modificarlo desde c#

Answer (score 2):

Aquí otra forma!

```
document.querySelector('#Label1').innerText = 'Tu Valor';
```

Saludos!